# Get posts by post title (Any title match and works as a OR condition)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am getting posts by particular post categories like if any of the category matches then it will get record. Now I want to add another field (get post by title) by getting posts. But it should work when any of the category doesn't match like OR condition instead of AND condition.

Code

```
$cat_array =  array();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cv',                        
    'category__in' => $cat_a
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Tried -

```
$cat_array =  array();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cv',                        
    'category__in' => $cat_a,
    'post-title' => $titleName //doesn't work
    'title' => $titleName //doesn't work
    's' => $titleName //don't know about it
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Ex.

```
Table records

Record - 1
Category posttitle
1       A


Record - 2
Category posttitle
2       B

Record - 3
Category posttitle
3       C

input - 
category - 1,2
title = 'anything'
output - record1, record2


input
category - 2,3
title = 'anything'
output - record2, record3

input
category - 4,5
title = 'C'
output - record3
```

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/18715

Comment: @Anant - Not able to understand your reference link code and don't know how can I use it in my code.